# How to create a raster in GDAL with Int64 datatype: Rasterizing a vector layer with very large ID as attribute

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I use the following python code to rasterize a vector `layer` using `gdal.RasterizeLayer`

```
output = 'F:\\TEMP\\rasterized.tif'
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(output, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Int32)
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_width, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_width))

gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], layer, options=["ATTRIBUTE=id"])
```

The `id` used as the `ATTRIBUTE` is larger than `Int32`.

I retrive the `layer` from a database with:

```
conn = ogr.Open('DB Connection parameters')
sql = "SELECT Statement"
layer = conn.ExecuteSQL(sql)
```

**Notes:**

- [The GDAL reference](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a22e22ce0a55036a96f652765793fb7a4) does not mention an `Int64` datatype, which is consistent with the [GeoTIFF format description](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html).
- However, the format description also mentions, that BigTIFF is supported when running `libtiff >= 4` (which is my case). [Reading the libtiff website](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/) I could not find a specific reference if `Int64` is supported or not.
- I installed `gdal 2.3.2` via `miniconda`

**Questions:** How to create a raster in GDAL that supports the `Int64` datatype? Does not have to be GeoTIFF.

Comment: Hi, I played around with the data types a bit (in ArcMap as well) and I'm fairly sure Int64 (i.e integers above 2147483647) is not supported as a datatype (for common rasters and ESRI shapefiles at least). I am not sure why exactly you would want Int64 as appose to float32, perhaps a file size issue? Anyway, I would say your best bet is just to use float32 for values > 2147483647 and < 3.4E+38.

Comment: Agree with Jascha. You can use float32 (also see gdal.GDT_Float64). See this answer for more explanation about the ranges of float and int: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746839/5326322